# Swift Remove app from the share sheet action

Tags: swift, share

Is it possible to remove in code Facebook app from share sheet action? (i don't talk about remove apps or turn on/off from Edit share menu action)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, it is possible, already found solution

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, may be because i didn't found answer till few minutes ago? Foud solution on YouTube...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, that's ok, hope it will help someone, because didn't found any solution on Stack...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items,
                                                          applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *exclude = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = exclude;
```

Comment: This is swift, not objective-c

Comment: oh sorry. @JoakimDanielson
but there is just syntax change.. I thought it might be usefull

Comment: @KrupaDetroja how to exclude the WhatsApp app